# Keras + Estimators + weighted samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

With Keras, adding sample weights that weight the loss function individually for each sample was simply done in the `model.fit()` method.

Now I am scaling the problem using Keras models (`tf.keras`), Estimators (`tf.estimator`) and Datasets (`tf.data`), via `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator`.

Is there a way to specify sample weights using an Estimator? The Estimator subclass `DNNClassifier` does have 'weight columns' which would work well if this functionality could be transferred.

Comment: I see quite a bit of work has been done on Keras+Estimators for tf 1.11.  But nothing about weighting the loss function.  Is it buried in the new release somewhere?  Is it on the radar?  Seems like a essential feature.

Comment: looks like model.fit() is supported in DistributedStrategy but is there the required support of reading sample weights from a tf.data.Dataset?

Comment: ok 1.12 supports sample_weights in the tf.data.Dataset that can be passed to the Keras model.fit() function.  This is working very nicely.  But putting that dataset inside an Estimator causes problems because the input_fn seems to only accept input and targets, not input-target-sample_weights.

Comment: Where did you see about sample_weights support in `tf.data.Dataset`?  I'm reading https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset

Comment: The support is actually at the level of tensorflow.python.keras.models.Sequential.fit(...). The fit method now accepts a dataset with sample_weights (in addition to features and labels). See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Sequential#fit

Comment: Can you not write a custom estimator? Wrap keras model in model_fn. Pass sample weight as a feature column in input_fn and weight the loss accordingly in model_fn?